# Facebook Page Tab for App redirecting links with fb_page and returning error

Tags: facebook, tabs, hyperlink, facebook-page, broken-links

I've made a Facebook Web App and added it to a already existing page, as a tab. When navigating through the app itself in it's original address, everything works fine.

The problem occurs when clicking links while using the app from the tab. I noticed Facebook added the **fb_page** plus a lot of numbers to the original link and it turns the link unreachable.

Does anyone know what can I do to correct it? I appreciate any help.